# How to set 3 items per row using flex when item has margin and border

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I would like to set 3 items per row. I tried something like that but, now I have 2 items per row because of margin and border. How should i implement this to have always 3 items per row

```css
.App {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 33%;
}
```

```html
    <div className="App">
      <div className="parent">
        <div className="item">1</div>
        <div className="item">2</div>
        <div className="item">3</div>
        <div className="item">4</div>
        <div className="item">5</div>
        <div className="item">6</div>
        <div className="item">7</div>
        <div className="item">8</div>
        <div className="item">9</div>
        <div className="item">10</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `width: calc(100%/3 - 12px);` on `.item`.

The `100%/3` will do 3 in a row. Then the `-12px` accounts for `margin: 5px` both sides = `10px`. Then the same with `border`. `1px` on either side affecting the `width` gives you `2px`. For a total of `12px`.

**Note:** you can use `box-sizing: border-box;` on `.item` to avoid having to use the `1px` on either side of the border in the calculation.

```css
.App {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

.parent {
  width: 600px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  width: calc(100%/3 - 12px);
  /*box-sizing: border-box; - would make the calc -10px instead of -12px*/
}
```

```html
<div class="App">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="item">1</div>
    <div class="item">2</div>
    <div class="item">3</div>
    <div class="item">4</div>
    <div class="item">5</div>
    <div class="item">6</div>
    <div class="item">7</div>
    <div class="item">8</div>
    <div class="item">9</div>
    <div class="item">10</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting flex-basis:33% on the item element instead of width

```css
.item {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 5px;
  flex-basis: 33%;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You have to keep in mind that a margin and border expands the size of the div. In your scenario, you have set the div to be 33%, which means the 3 divs in total occupy 99% of the parents width. The remaining 1% is not enough for all the margins and borders.

What I suggest is put the div size to around 30% , or use padding instead of margin .

Comment: With padding I will not have break between each item